# Multisig Wallet in Mist created but is in creating loop

Tags: mist, wallets, multisignature

We are using MIST and we've created a Multisig Wallet. It is actually creating (still grey and creating) and my partner imported it and it is importing (also grey). Is there some BUG in MIST why it is not working?

Here is the contract successful created  https://etherscan.io/address/0x7bf08cb1732e1246c65b51b83ac092f9b4ebb8c6

Any idea what todo?

Thanks for your help.
Nicky

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround

Open:
Develop -> Toggle developer tools -> Ethereum Wallet

In the console:

```
Wallets.find().fetch()
Wallets.remove("_id")
```

Done!